# Passing parameters from one query to a view in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, view, ms-access-2003, squirrel-sql

If you define a query in Microsoft Access,

For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM T_Employees t WHERE t.LastName=[LastName]
```

a popup dialog will display asking you to enter a value for `LastName`.  `LastName` a named parameter.

Now from here one can also create a view

```
CREATE VIEW paramTest AS SELECT * FROM T_Employees t WHERE t.LastName=[LastName]
```

But when calling this view in another query, the parameter is ignored....

So how does one call the view created above from another query and specify the value of the named parameter within that view?  (preferably without VBA, I'm trying to use it to write a query involving a view in SQuirreL SQL).

Comment: Note: Re-retrieving the content of the VIEW's SQL statement using Scripts->Create Select Script yields a missing WHERE clause that I included above.

Comment: Also I know you can include parameters using the `:paramName` syntax in SQUirrel SQL, but you cannot create `VIEW`s that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `CREATE VIEW` statement creates the named query, `paramTest`, with this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_Employees AS t
WHERE (((t.LastName)=[LastName]));
```

When running that query, the db engine does not interpret `[LastName]` to be a pararmeter, so doesn't pop up the parameter dialog, because the name of the parameter is the same as the field name.  Essentially, the db engine returns the rows where each `LastName` field is equal to itself ... all rows.

If you want to create a parameter query which works, give the parameter a name which doesn't match any field names in the data source.  And, as Ron mentioned. `CREATE VIEW` won't allow you to create a parameter query.  However you can create one with `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE PROCEDURE paramTest " & _
    "(Which_LastName TEXT(255)) AS" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT * FROM T_Employees t WHERE t.LastName=[Which_LastName];"
```

Comment: Is it possible to then call the stored procedure in a query, with the parameters?

Comment: I don't know how it would work from that Squirley SQL thing you mentioned.  From pyodbc, I could open a cursor with: `"SELECT * FROM paramTest", "Doe"` ... IOW, include parameter value after a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

VIEWS do not allow parameters. Think of them more like tables than queries. Normally a stored procedure is used when parameters are needed. In order to incorporate a parameter in a view, you must create a table with the parameter value and include it in the VIEW SQL. The parameter table typically includes a USER ID to avoid concurrent request conflicts.

Comment: Access has stored procedures?

Comment: I am not familiar with SQUirrel SQL and assumed procedures were supported.

Comment: It looks like they are...it lists them in the `Objects` panel as `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Great. The VIEW/PARM TABLE method is tricky. Seems like HansUp's solution will do the trick.